# Keeping laptop charger plugged-in, while charging stops at 80%

Tags: laptop, battery, power, battery-life, charging

I have an Acer Gaming Laptop, it comes with an inbuilt feature, that stops charging the battery when the capacity is above 80%, it can be found under Acer Care Center named as Battery Charge Limiter.

I have read from many forums that, enabling this feature will help to slowdown the battery health depletion. So did I.

I am a power user, I need to render my videos from the same laptop. Rendering takes many hours. I keep the laptop over a well ventilated surface and at optimal room temperature.

Considering such an power usage, *I keep the charger plugged in all the time, while the battery charger limit is enabled*, as I said it stops charging and remains at 80%

**NOW MY QUESTION IS**

*Is it safe to keep the charger plugged-in during rendering, for a prolonged period of 10 hours while the battery charger limiter is enabled.?*

*Will this setup damage my battery ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Acer Gaming Laptop ... comes with an inbuilt feature, that stops
> charging the battery when the capacity is above 80%
>
> Is it safe to keep the charger plugged-in during rendering, for a
> prolonged period of 10 hours while the battery charger limiter is
> enabled.?  Will this setup damage my battery ?

It is safe to keep your laptop plugged in and on charge with the charging limited to 80% .   That is by design and it is safe to do.

Your battery will not be harmed. It will wear out at some point - It will just last longer before it does finally wear out.

I have two laptops here that I leave running all the time. Lockdown issues.  The battery health remains fine.